# Removing 'executeTests' timing output during sbt test run

Tags: scala, sbt

When running scala tests information like `| => project / Test / executeTests 204s` is constantly displayed at the bottom. Is there any way to hide it by changing some config?

Comment: Why? What's the context behind this need?

Comment: Also, you're running SBT in interactive mode, right? Have you tried non interactive mode?

Comment: @GaëlJ I am using `sbt test` in combination with `script -c` in a Github action to preserve colors. However the test run output gets kind of polluted with these messages.

Comment: I have tried the non-interactive mode by adding `shell` to a sbt command but it didn't help.

Comment: Strange, we run SBT in our pipelines without this being displayed. I don't have code at hands now to check but pretty sure we don't do anything specific.